# apache-nifi: distributedMapCacheServer how to start

Tags: apache-nifi

perhaps these will look as a silly questions: I have no idea how to use the DistributedMapCacheServer. How do I start it ? Is it supposed to be within nifi or do I have install it as secondary package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DistributedMapCacheServer can be started just like any other Controller Service, by configuring it to be valid and hitting the "start" button.

The unique thing about the DistributedMapCacheServer is that processors work with the cache by utilizing a DistributedMapCacheClientService[1]. So you will create both a Server and Client Service. Then configure the processor to use the Client Service. Next start both the server and service. Finally start the processor.

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService/index.html

Comment: Ok I got it... I'm really newbie with nifi and have tons of things to do. You help is very appriciated. Is there a video which shows all the nifi feaures ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd, not a problem. Here is an older video but it gives a step by step for new users and just about all of it still applies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgTGAWLC170

Comment: I'd also recommend reading the User documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

Comment: Just another question: how to set how long the data stay into the cache ?

Comment: Data will stay in the cache until either it is removed by a processor using it or when more space is needed in the cache ("max count"  and "eviction strategy" are properties of the cache server). See the docs for the property descriptions: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html

Answer (score 3):

To start DistributedMapCacheServer , you need to first create it .
It will be created through NiFi UI ,by selecting the controller setting tab from the top right side menu .click on + button and add DistributedMapCacheServer . configure  it and enable it .